# How to solve route.params undefined in react native screens typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-router, navigation, stack-navigator

I have this below where I fetched country's names from an API, and displayed them on the screen using `routes`. Now, I'd like to display `item.country` as the `headerTitle`. However, I am getting an `undefined` error for the `route.params.` How can I fix this?

**LocationDataScreen.tsx**

```
function LocationDataScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { item } = navigation.state.params || {};  
  const countryName = item.country;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{countryName}</Text>
      <Text>{item.cases}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**ItemView.tsx**

```
const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <RectButton
        onPress={() =>
          navigate("LocationDataScreen", { item: item, name: item.country })
        }
      >
        <Text style={[styles.itemStyle, { textTransform: "capitalize" }]}>
          {item.id}
          {item.country.toUpperCase()}
        </Text>
      </RectButton>
    );
  };
```

**App.tsx**

```
<AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="SearchScreen">
  <AppStack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
  <AppStack.Screen
          name="LocationDataScreen"
          component={LocationDataScreen}
          options={({ route }) => ({
            headerLargeTitle: true,
            title: route.params.item,
          })}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply that you are passing params to `LocationDataScreen.tsx` in a wrong manner.

Use this instead:

**ItemView**

```
const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <RectButton
        onPress={() =>
          navigate("LocationDataScreen", { ...item })
        }
      >
        <Text style={[styles.itemStyle, { textTransform: "capitalize" }]}>
          {item.id}
          {item.country.toUpperCase()}
        </Text>
      </RectButton>
    );
  };
```

**LocationDataScreen.tsx**

```
function LocationDataScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { country, cases } = route.params

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{country}</Text>
      <Text>{cases}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am assuming here that your  **item** in this line `const ItemView = ({ item }) => {` looks something like this.

```
item: {
   country: 'Italy',
   cases: 10
}
```

If you could add your api response **[here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.f86c0b3e78534002b83d18b0e93d4917)**.
Let me know in the comments once you have added. Also share the link to the same in the comment.

Comment: The api response is in this question right here, which you responded to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322053/flatlist-onpress-to-different-screen-with-data. But, I am getting `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.params')

Comment: Can you add this line  "console.log('navigation check', navigation)" above the return statement in LocationDataScreen.tsx ?? Let me know what gets printed. Would be great if you could expand the "navigation" object if you are receiving any value. An image(SS) would work just fine. @dannym

Comment: UPDATE: I did some research and found that navigation doesn't have 'state' in functions. 
 "this.props.navigation.state.params" only works when you make use of a "class". However since you are using functions, u will have to use this 
`. const { country, cases } = route.params  ` in LocationDetailScreen. And for passing values from InputView, use this:  
<----   
onPress={() =>
          navigate("LocationDataScreen", { ...item })
        } 

@dannym

Comment: Solution updated here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322053/flatlist-onpress-to-different-screen-with-data) as well

Comment: Thank you for this information! Will make sure to keep this mind for the future :)

Comment: Can u flag my solution as the correct answer please... here as well as in the other question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322053/flatlist-onpress-to-different-screen-with-data

Answer (score 2):

you should do it like below

```
options={({route}) => ({
            headerLargeTitle: true,
            title: route.params.name,
          })}
```

You will have to pass the name like below

```
navigation.navigate("LocationDataScreen",{name:item.name});
```

Make sure that you have a setup like below for to access the params

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
  SearchScreen: undefined;
  LocationDataScreen: { name: string };
};

const AppStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

Comment: I have updated my code, but the route.params is still `undefined`. The route is `var route: Route<"LocationDataScreen", undefined>`

Comment: why are you using navigation.state.params ? doenst route.params work?

Comment: route.params gives the same `undefined` error.

Comment: have you created a route prop by importing import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native'; ?

Comment: Yes, but where do I use that in App.tsx ?

Comment: you have to set it up at navigator level as specified here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-the-navigator, then you will have access to params

Comment: Thanks for the docs. Could you give an example of how I can do it here ?

Comment: It works now. But, I don't want the header to say "Name". I want it to be the country's name where the user selects from flatlist.

Comment: when you pass the item navigate("LocationDataScreen",{name:item.name}); do this

Answer (score 0):

As per react navigation docs, set the type as;

```
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

export type StackParamList = {
  screen1: undefined;
  screen2: {propkey: proptype, ...}; // this object defines the params and their types passed to the screen
};

export type ScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<
  StackParamList,
  "screen1"
>;
```

Then in your screen;

```
import {ScreenProps} from 'path_to_above_file' // or put the above defined type in the same screen
```

Then defined the interface for the screen;

```
interface CurrentScreenProps {
  navigation: DashProps["navigation"];
  route: DashProps["route"];
}
```

After this, when using route.params.key, it gives the warning thast route.params may be an empty object. To remove that warning, i gave the route a custom type;

```
interface CurrentScreenProps {
   ...,
   route: {
     key1: key1type, // e,g, name: string;
     //...other keys and their types

   }

}
```